# ALTER TABLE command gets ignored when table definition is imported

Tags: mysql

I am running PhpMyAdmin v4.8.0.1. I exported a table and thus, have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_site_settings` (
  `settings_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    
  `usage_limit_per_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
ALTER TABLE `wp_site_settings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`settings_id`);
```

As we can see from the above code, the `ALTER TABLE` part is present **after** the `CREATE TABLE`. I want this `ADD PRIMARY KEY` to be a part of the `CREATE TABLE` itself, so that it can be exported as:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_site_settings` (
  `settings_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    
  `usage_limit_per_user` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`settings_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need it in the above way because I am trying to use the above in a custom WordPress plugin. If the `ADD PRIMARY KEY` is performed using the `ALTER TABLE` command, the whole command gets ignored and the resultant table does not contain the `PRIMARY KEY`.

This is just an example of one table. I need the solution to work for other 20+ custom tables as well, so any workaround/fix is appreciated.

**NOTE:** I am aware that the `ALTER TABLE` was separated intentionally as per  [+ rfe #1004 Create indexes at the end in SQL export](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/home:ecsos:aggregation/phpMyAdmin/phpMyAdmin.changes?expand=1)

Comment: Can you use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead?

Comment: @Nick Thanks you so much! Using `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_site_settings` and then selecting the `FULL TEXT` option seems to show me the desired output. But how can I go about achieving the same output with 20+ tables in one go, without having to run the command for each of the tables?

Comment: You could generate a dynamic SQL query using something like `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SHOW_CREATE_TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME) SEPARATOR ';') 
FROM \`TABLES\`
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '<your database name>'` and then prepare and execute that?

Comment: I used the following syntax: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SHOW_CREATE_TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME) SEPARATOR ';') FROM `TABLES` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE woo2;` and it threw me the following MySQL error: `#1146 - Table 'woo2.tables' doesn't exist`. FYI, `woo2` is my Database name,

Comment: Sorry I had changed database on my server, it should be `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SHOW_CREATE_TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME) SEPARATOR ';') FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '<your database name>'`

Comment: @Nick That seems to have fixed the query. Thank you. But I had to change the following in your query: `SHOW_CREATE_TABLE ` to `SHOW CREATE TABLE `. When I ran it, it was showing me the SHOW CREATE TABLES but when I ran multiple of those in the same query, only the `SHOW..` part for the first table ran. How can I make it show the structure for the other tables as well?

Comment: Not sure where I got `SHOW_CREATE` from! Unfortunately I think you will have to run the queries separately as it's not possible to execute more than one statement in a prepared query. I should have thought of that earlier...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will work on it a bit more to see what can be done.

Comment: @Nick Hi, sorry it's been a while and I could not get back to you earlier. I would like you to get the rep for helping me out, so could you please post your reply as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Judging from re-reading the comments you probably did as much of the work as I did (especially correcting my `SHOW_CREATE_TABLE` - still have no idea where that came from! :-). I'm happy if you've got a working solution.

Comment: It would not have been possible without you, so I just wanted to make sure that you get the credit for the same. That would make me happy :)